# ExtJS 4 state provider

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox, state

I have the following example (http://jsfiddle.net/a473n/1/). The code is this:

```
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.LocalStorageProvider());

Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Checkbox', {
    stateful: true,
    boxLabel: 'Click me',
    stateEvents: ['change'],
    stateId: 'my-checkbox',
    renderTo: document.body 
});
```

When I use Chrome's debugger to view Resources and see local storage, I can see an entry for 'my-checkbox', but when I click the button that represents the checkbox in the page UI, I don't see the value of checked or unchecked being written to local storage. The value in local storage never changes. What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The state data comes from the [`getState`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-getState) method. For checkboxes, it is inherited from `AbstractComponent`, and it merely saves the size of the component (see [the code](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/source/AbstractComponent.html#Ext-AbstractComponent-method-getState)). So you'll have to provide your own implementation of this method if your wish is to save and restore the value.

Of course, there is a second step, you'll also have to override the [`applyState`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.state.Stateful-method-applyState) method to apply the extra things you'll be saving.

I've [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a473n/3/) to demonstrate this:

```
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.LocalStorageProvider());

Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Checkbox', {
    stateful: true,
    boxLabel: 'dasfasdf',
    stateEvents: ['change'],
    stateId: 'my-checkbox',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()

    ,getState: function() {
        return {
            checked: this.getValue()
        };
    }

    ,applyState: function(state) {
        this.setValue(state && state.checked);
    }
});
```

Voilà! Value-wise stateful checkbox!

If you want to do this with something more involved than a checkbox, it would probably be a good idea to also call the parent of the overridden methods. Check the implementations for the actual components, to see if you need it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! You're the best. Was really starting to pull out my hair!